# disable keyguard, statusbar and navigation bar on AOSP Android 11 system

Tags: android-11, aosp

How do we disable the Keyguard to appear on the device after the boot up on Android 11 onwards.
Also how should I remove the Status bar and navigation bar to appear from the device always.

I do not want to add any Full screen flags through my applications. I want the screen to be in kiosk mode always.

Are there any flags or properties in AOSP Frameworks or device make-file which we can override to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide navbar and status bar by setting the height of these dimens to 0dp.

- `status_bar_height_portrait`
- `navigation_bar_height`
- `navigation_bar_height_landscape`
- `navigation_bar_width`

For disabling the keyguard by default, you can set the following bool in Settings Provider to `true`

- `def_lockscreen_disabled`

Comment: Hello. How to set these dimensions that you mentioned above? I'm asking the procedure that is to be followed.

Comment: You have to edit these in frameworks_base overlays or define your own TARGET_PRODUCT_OVERLAYS.